# After normalising my data using DataPreparer while using random forest and SVM, why do my data values become negative?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, random-forest, database-normalization

I am working on predictive modeling where I need to predict whether an online customer ends up purchasing a product on a website or not, and I am using Random Forest Classifier and SVM since it's a classification problem.

After creating the fitting splits for training, testing, and validation sets, I dummify, standardize and normalize my data. However, after I normalize the sets, their values become all negative. Is there a way to change that and why does it happen?

The code that I am using to normalize my fitting sets is as below:

```
data_preparer = DataPreparer(one_hot_encoder, standard_scaler)
data_preparer.prepare_data(fitting_splits.train_set).head()
data_preparer.prepare_data(fitting_splits.validation_set).head()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation from sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler can help here:

> The standard score of a sample x is calculated as:
>
> z = (x - u) / s
>
> where u is the mean of the training samples or zero if
> with_mean=False, and s is the standard deviation of the training
> samples or one if with_std=False.

Based on this equation, if x (the individual value currently being scaled) is less than the mean of the variable, then your scaled value will be negative.